# instance is not matching with filename under if statment

Tags: python

I have got a list of instance id calling function:
`instance_ID = get_instance_id()`. howver when i compare instanceid with file name it matching nothing though I can see it matching when i run: `#print("{} - {}".format(instance,filename))`

```
def main():
    instance_ID = get_instance_id()
    #print(instance_ID)
    os.chdir(f'{basedir}/../config/')
    config_dir = Path()
    
    for file in config_dir.glob(f"**/*.yaml"):
        for instance in instance_ID:
            filename = file.stem
            #print("{} - {}".format(instance,filename))
            if instance == filename:
                print(instance)            
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you sure that the types that you are trying to match are the same ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code, example data (i.e. filenames, I guess), expected output, and actual output. You can [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

But just found the issue.there was a space in the csv file from where I am taking those instance ID.That caused the issue.after i instance.strip() problem resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).